# "Bad Image" with Heat in Wix 3.0 with typelibs

Tags: wix, installation, wix3, typelib, heat

When using `heat` (from Wix 3.0.4805.0) to generate Wix documents off of a typelib that's generated by Visual Studio, I have been getting an error.  A window pops up that says:

> 'heat.exe - Bad Image'
>
> The application or DLL c:\path\to\file.tlb is not a valid Windows image.  Please check this against your installation diskette.

But then after we press 'ok', it continues on and successfully generates

It looks like [this bug report on the wix bugboard says it was fixed in a release previous to mine, but it seems not to be](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1583346&group_id=105970&atid=642714).  They say that the error occurs because it tries to load it as a DLL first (which fails) but then continues on to do the right thing.

This is happening on Windows XP SP3.

Anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a later build. There have been significant bug fixes to heat since 4805 build.